# Federated access to desktop and network resources in MS AD domains

Tags: active-directory, authentication

We are looking for a way to provide members of three loosely connected organizations with access to authenticated resources such as file shares, printers, and lab computers. I've seen federation facilities for web resources; is ther something similar for
domain logins?  Our Active directory domains are not connected so
we would have to use email addresses for the username to insure uniqueness. Is there any openid like mechanism that works for AD logins?

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply create trusts between the forests and grant the users rights to the remote resources?

Comment: That is the direction we are leaning.  There are potential issues around campus software agreements, privileges granted to general authenticated users, and management.  Nothing insurmountable.  The biggest issue is that one of the three organizations uses AD, but their primary authentication system is Sun One, so we're going to have to explore how Sun One can be integrated into an AD trust.

Comment: Assuming Sun One uses LDAP then you can do an external trust to it so that it can pass authentication over to the other LDAP system.